# Intercepting Headers and Modifying On The Fly

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am tasked with developing a mitmproxy script, something I have never done before.

I am trying to modify "Location" headers on the fly during http-flow on a reverse proxy instance in mitmproxy, these headers are often different but my main goal right now is to simply detect them in a static manner.

I am running mitmproxy as such:
`mitmdump --set flowdetail:3 -s rproxy.py -p 8080 --mode reverse:http://www.com`
^ That is not the real URL of question of course.

Say if I have the header being sent from the server
Location: http://www.com/example-location

But I want to change it to
Location: http://localhost:8080/example-location

I have tried every example I could find on google, including the ones on StackOverFlow.
Some things I have tried without any success.

```
from mitmproxy import http
import sys

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    flow.request.host = "http://localhost:8080/example-location"
```

```
from mitmproxy import http
import sys

def response(flow):
    flow.repsonse.headers['Location'] = ["http://localhost:8080/example-location"]
    flow.repsonse.headers['Location'] = "http://localhost:8080/example-location" ## I tried this line separately without the above line
```

And

```
from mitmproxy import http
import sys

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    flow.repsonse.headers['Location'] = ["http://localhost:8080/example-location"]
    flow.repsonse.headers['Location'] = "http://localhost:8080/example-location" ## I tried this line separately without the above line
```

How do I do this correctly?

If it is not possible to manipulate this header (but why shouldn't it be) what are options do I have?

Comment: Are you sure your addon is really executed? Are you sure the `Location` header is sent by the server? Typically a location is sent by the client to the server in the request. I would add some print or log calls to verify that it is really executed. besides that your code looks good, compare it with the response part of this example: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#http-trailers

Comment: Also please note that `repsonse` != `response`. You should see an error mitmproxy's event log.